# Tabbed content won't work with multiple divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to Javascript and am working on the following:

```
$('.tabs-holder li').click(function () {
    var tabID = $(this).attr('data-tab-id');
    $(this).closest('.tabbed-content').find('.tabs-holder li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).closest('.tabbed-content').find('.content-holder').children('.tab-content').removeClass('active').siblings('.tab-content[data-tab-id=' + tabID + ']').addClass('active');
});
```

I'm trying to get it to work on all divs with a `data-tab-id` of the same value, but it's only acting on the one div.

JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/dynaf9pc/8/

Comment: whats the issue? Im not sure I understand

Comment: @jmore009 the code above shows the content for whichever tab you select. It does this by displaying the div with the relevant id eg `data-tab-id="1"`. I've added another div with the same id eg. `data-tab-id="1"` but this content doesn't display when the relevant tab is selected. Make sense? It's a difficult one to explain... So what I'm trying to do is to get ALL divs with the same ids eg. `data-tab-id="1"` to display when the relevant tab is selected.

Comment: it appears to be working in that fiddle you posted. Is it not? I see the content blocks changing when i click

Comment: ohhh its the container at the bottom that should change too? Thats what you're referring to?

Comment: @jmore009 Yep, container at the bottom :) It works great for the first lot of content but I want it to change the second lot of content at the same time in the `<div class="content-holder">` div at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That content container you're trying to target is a sibling of `.tabbed-content` so you need to back out to the parent `.tabbed-content` and then navigate to its sibling like so:

```
   $(this).closest(".tabbed-content")
          .siblings(".content-holder")
          .find('.tab-content[data-tab-id=' + tabID + ']')
          .addClass('active')
          .siblings()
          .removeClass('active');
```

Also I refactored some of your JS that was redundant and made it shorter by chaining your selectors:

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dynaf9pc/14/)

Comment: I have struck one problem from your solution though, it's the same problem just an extra layer. Each of the two divs that you fixed to change simultaneously are actually wrapped in another div setting column widths (I had simplified the first JSFiddle as I thought the div hierarchy wouldn't matter!) I can't seem to back out of these ones, one is `<div class="medium-8 columns">` and the second is `<div class="medium-4 columns">`. From what you showed above I thought I could just back out of `<div class="medium-8 columns">` too and it would work? http://jsfiddle.net/dynaf9pc/20/

Comment: yeah so adding wrappers will throw stuff off. You have to go up to more levels so instead of chaining this you might as well use another target. It will be cleaner: [http://jsfiddle.net/dynaf9pc/21/](http://jsfiddle.net/dynaf9pc/21/)

Comment: yeah no problem. its not that hard once you get the hang of it. The hardest part is understanding how to navigate through the DOM elements and the hierarchy of your html

Answer (score 0):

You are not iterating through the elements. If you add each(), it will go through multiple div's that it will find.

```
$('.tabs-holder li').click(function () {
    var tabID = $(this).attr('data-tab-id');
    $(this).closest('.tabbed-content').find('.tabs-holder li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).closest('.tabbed-content')
        .find('.content-holder')
        .children('.tab-content')
        .removeClass('active')
        .siblings('.tab-content[data-tab-id=' + tabID + ']')
        .each(function() {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        })
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work... Applied it to the JSFiddle and can't get it to work